# haskell readFile from file line by line

Tags: haskell, line, readfile

Haskell programming
how to use readFile
I use getLine but it should react with a user for each command
But i need to read lines from text file and process the input line

```
text <- readFile "input.txt"
let linii = lines text
interact (unlines . (map calculate) . linii)
```

Answer (score 0):

So `interact` is to do IO using *stdin* and *stdout*. If instead of *stdin* you want to use a file for input, that's fine you can use the `readFile` function as you are already doing:

```
applyOnFileLines :: FilePath -> (String -> String) -> IO ()
applyOnFileLines filePath func = do
  file <- readFile filePath
  putStr . unlines
         . map func
         . lines
         $ file
```

Comment: Might as well remove the `do` notation here since we're already working mostly with function composition anyway: `applyOnFileLines filePath f = putStr =<< unlines . map f . lines <$> readFile filePath`. Also I think it would be better if `applyOnFileLines` took its arguments in the other order, `f` before `filePath`. Makes for clearer reading and better partial application.

Comment: Fair enough, I wrote it like this thinking it would be easier for OP. Otherwise if you like a more *point-free* style, something like this could work: `onLinesToFile func = (putStr . unlines . map func . lines =<<) . readFile`

Comment: Thank u, but really i am not good in Haskell, please send me a file is ready to run including the function and  where to place it and how to call this function from another function

Comment: @hatemsalama Nobody is going to do that. Stack Overflow is for getting help with specific, well-defined hurdles that are getting in your way of solving a problem. It is not a program-writing service where answerers will write your whole program for you. As for "how to call this function from another function": it's not too much of a stretch to say that that's exactly what the type annotation is!

Comment: I need help that "how to call this function from another function?"